# UAE Tourist Visa

Tags: indian-citizens, money, tourist-visas, uae

I'm planning to visit the UAE for tourism purposes with my family. I also have a cousin residing in Sharjah and it was his idea to come along just for a family holiday.

My queries are as below:

1. Can I apply for UAE visa through any of the local tour operators?
2. I wish to stay around 8-9 days at my cousin's place so will I need an invitation letter from him?
3. Is there any limit to carry AED (Arab Emirates Dirham) as if I convert INR to AED in UAE, it might be a bit expensive compared to converting in India and then taking it to UAE.

Comment: Clarify whether you're traveling on an Indian passport?

Comment: Ya,Me alongwith my family have a normal Indian passport

Answer (score 2):

> 3. I there any limit to carry AED (Arab Emirates Dirham)

[IATA Travel Centre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/AE-United-Arab-Emirates-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm):

> ### Currency rules
>
> **Currency Import regulations:**
>
> Local currency (United Arab Em. Dirham-AED) and foreign currencies:
>   allowed, however, currency exceeding AED 100,000.- (or equivalent)
>   must be declared on arrival.
>
> **Currency Export regulations:**
>
> Local currency (United Arab Em. Dirham-AED) and foreign currencies: no
>   restrictions.

I must though caution that the same source seems to be grossly out-of-date regarding Indian currency into India. However here only the AED 100,000 seems at all likely to change over time and I presume is vastly more than you expect to spend in UAE over a week or two.

Comment: Thanks for the info..
The only reason I asked is,as I'll going to Dubai,many of my colleagues have given a list of things to bring back for them..

Comment: @pnuts-I would carry max of 4-5k AED which would be  allowed as per the limit.Also just want to know,where can I find currency exchange kiosks in UAE?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can I apply for UAE visa through any of the local tour operators?

Yes, the tour operators will act as your sponsor and usually apply for visa online on your behalf. Tourist visas are usually granted within a day's time. There are restrictions, however, for people from certain countries.

> 2. I wish to stay around 8-9 days at my cousin's place so will I need an invitation letter from him?

Not at all. Where you stay is not an issue. With a tourist visa, you can travel all over the UAE.